# Limiting permissions for 3rd party software modules in Android Development

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-permissions, user-permissions

How can we restrict permissions for 3rd party adware and other libraries?

I don't want 3rd party adware to access camera and especially database data.

Is there a possibility to completely isolate 3rd party modules (such as unity or advertisement modules) from the application we are developing?

Can we configure an activity-based or module-based permission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're including libraries in your app, there is implicit trust. They usually have access to pretty much everything your app does.

However, if you [look at your merged manifest](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts) and see a library has added a permission / service / receiver etc you don't want your app to have, you can remove them very easily.

A common use case is similar to yours, some libraries may request things like microphone for functionality that you do not need that library to have.

Here is an example of how to remove a permission from a library from the [manifest documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests#marker_selector):

```
<permission android:name="permissionOne"
    tools:node="remove"
    tools:selector="com.example.lib1">
```

If you'd like to remove the permission from your app entirely, just remove the `selector`:

```
<permission android:name="permissionOne"
    tools:node="remove">
```

Of course, if you're removing bits of the manifest that a library expects to have, it may stop working (although I haven't personally experienced this).

Comment: a) As I understand from your answer, if my app needs bluetooth permission, I cannot remove or somehow block the bluetooth permission of 3rd party soft, is my thought correct?

b) What if the third party application asks for dynamic permission other than the manifest? Is there such an opportunity? Or do you think this situation can be prevented?

c) Is there a way to protect important information including user profiles such as database? If a database such as sqlite/firebase is created, can different activities or 3rd party lib access the db data directly and unhindered?

thank you again.

Comment: a) It'll be tricky to block for ALL third party libraries, but you can block for specific ones (e.g. those that have it in manifest) using the `selector`. 
b) All permissions have to be in the manifest to be requested. If you look at the merged manifest (link in answer), you can see what permissions libraries are asking for. 
c) Sure, usually you'd encrypt it. By default, DBs are stored unencrypted in your app's files somewhere. That being said, I've never heard of a library maliciously stealing app files.